# Why are integers treated as enums in this code snippet?

Tags: java, android, enums, int, android-permissions

I'm writing my first android app following guides and resources on Android Developers. My background: obviously zero experience with android development and little experience with java. The latter could be the reason why I'm stuck.

So, take a look at this code snippet on handling permissions (from https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting):

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

// MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
// app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
// result of the request.
```

As you can see it says that MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an int constant.

Then, it shows the implementation of the callback method onRequestPermissionsResult():

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // contacts-related task you need to do.
            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}
```

As you can see the switch statement treats requestCode not as an int, but it looks like it's treating it as if it was an Enum. But if I try to pass an enum to requestPermissions() it gives me an error because the method signature requires requestCode to be an int.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is a long story. To be short - performance and memory effectivity.

Here more details https://android.jlelse.eu/android-performance-avoid-using-enum-on-android-326be0794dc3

And here google's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE

But nowadays it is okay to use enums in your code if you really need them.

About `requestCode`, Android system use only lower 16 bits for it. (<65k). More details about it you can find in FragmentActivity class, limitation needed to address result to correct fragment.